# Ajax long polling using socket.io & mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm just getting into node.js, socket.io, etc. and I'm trying to figure out how I can constantly retrieve results from a MongoDB collection.

New records are inserted every second or less so it needs to constantly update.  How can I do this in node using socket.io & Mongo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **very general** so the answer can only be **very general** too:

1. Create a socket.io connection between your client and your server.
2. Every time a new record is created on the server, send it via socket.io to the client.